# Update SQL Database from Modified Datatable

Tags: datagridview, datatable

I have an application where I populate several DataGridviews by using the following function.

```
dgvMyStats.DataSource = GetDataTable("Select * from MyMonthlySalesStats")

Protected Friend Function GetDataTable(ByVal sqlCommand As String) As DataTable

    Dim connectionString As String = ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings("iView.My.MySettings.iViewConnectionString").ConnectionString
    Dim iViewConnection As SqlConnection = New SqlConnection(connectionString)
    Dim command As New SqlCommand(sqlCommand, iViewConnection)
    Dim adapter As SqlDataAdapter = New SqlDataAdapter()
    Dim table As New DataTable

    adapter.SelectCommand = command

    table.Locale = System.Globalization.CultureInfo.InvariantCulture
    adapter.Fill(table)

    ' Close Connection
    iViewConnection.Close()

    Return table

End Function
```

This works like a charm.  However, now I need to update my database from one of my datagridviews.  I have changed the properties of the datagridview to allow the creation of new rows.  But now I need to know how to push this updated datagridview data back to my SQL Database.  Any help is much appricated.  Thanks in advance...

Comment: You could have typed the title of this post alone in Google and found several well documented guides on how to do this. Perhaps you should provide the code that you tried but are having problems with?

Answer (score 0):

I figured it out.  I had to build another function

```
Protected Friend Function SQLDirect(ByVal sqlCommand As String)

    Dim connectionString As String = ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings("iView.My.MySettings.iViewConnectionString").ConnectionString
    Dim iViewConnection As SqlConnection = New SqlConnection(connectionString)
    Dim command As New SqlCommand(sqlCommand, iViewConnection)
    Dim returnValue As String

    ' Open Connection
    iViewConnection.Open()

    ' Execute SQL Command
    returnValue = Convert.ToInt32(command.ExecuteScalar())

    ' Close Connection
    iViewConnection.Close()

    ' Return Value back to calling procedure
    Return returnValue

End Function
```

I use this function to submit my UPDATES and INSERTS.  I hope this helps someone else.  Thanks...